# Can't use a variable for importing a less file

Tags: less, gruntjs

Don't know if this is a bug or just me. I have the following code in my main.less file:

```
@import 'settings.less';
@theme_branding: 'themes/blue/branding.less';
@import @theme_branding;
```

This outputs the following erorr on my terminal (I am using Grunt by the way)

```
undefined_methodError: Object #<Object> has no method 'genCSS' in less/main.less on line null, column 0:
```

Not very helpful if an error is on line NULL

However, instead of using a variable as the import path I just used a string instead. This works totally fine

```
@import 'settings.less';
@theme_branding: 'themes/blue/branding.less';
@import 'themes/blue/branding.less';
```

I have commented everything out. I only had the settings file importing with no errors and everything else as well. Its just when I try to `@import @var_name` that it starts to give me issues.

Am I doing this wrong? I tried using the code on less's site and still get issues.

Comment: `@import @theme_branding;` this syntax is not supported. Use `@import "@{theme_branding}";` instead (See http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements).

Comment: I just figured that out but I am getting another issue I will update my question.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I just figured out why I was having issues. I answered my own question below let me know if it makes sense and if not I will rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So apparently less doesn't save strings as strings. How the following variable is displayed is as follows:

```
@var = 'path/to/file';
@import @var
```

This equates to

```
@import path/to/file
```

Which is not a string according to css. The variable will have to be enclosed in quotation marks like so:

```
@var = 'path/to/file';
@import = "@{var}";
```

This equates to:

```
@import 'path/to/file';
```

So this worked in my main.less file but I was having issues when importing these variables from a settings file. I figured out why this didn't work for me. In my settings file I had something like:

```
@file: 'file';
@path: 'path/to/@{file}';
```

then in my main.less file

```
@import 'settings.less';
@import '@{path}';
```

This gave me an error, however because I already encapsulated the variable @path in a string less reads it as a full string now and I don't have to surround it with quotes the second time. So this was the fix for main.less:

```
@import 'settings.less';
@import @path;
```

Comment: Not that's not because "less doesn't save strings as strings", it's just because Less requires `@import` to be followed by an explicit string and not by a variable or any other entity (no matter if the variable itself contains string). Less variables are no macros - they are not immediately expanded to their values independently of context.